# Getting <td> index from a 3*3 Table

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am new to javascript and phonegap. I am practicing database handling in phonegap. Here I have a table of data from database. I need to get the td index when it's clicked. My table is in 3*3 format. I have the code of table here:

```
var getDB = document.getElementById("mainDB");
var i = 0;
while (i < res.rows.length) {
   getDB.innerHTML="<table>";
   for(var j=0; j<3; j++){
      getDB.innerHTML=getDB.innerHTML+"<tr>";
      for(var k=0;k<3;k++){
         getDB.innerHTML=getDB.innerHTML+"<td class='tdIndex'><h5 align='center'>"+res.rows.item(i).name+"</h5></td>";
         i++;
      }
      getDB.innerHTML=getDB.innerHTML+"</tr>";
   }
   getDB.innerHTML=getDB.innerHTML+"</table>";
};
```

I am not sure if I have given enough here. If anything else is needed from my main code, please let me know. I need a jquery or javascript solution to get the td index or serial of the total 9 td when clicked.

I am having another problem here that I forgot to add. That is, the table here suppose to present itself as a 3*3 table. But when I am testing it on my phone, only one element is coming in each row instead of 3. I mean it becomes a list of 9 items or something like that. May be td element is not working correctly. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If i understand correctly, you need td index on click, however it's a double index, of row and cell.

```
$('td').click(function(){
    var row = $(this).parent().index();
    var cell = $(this).index();
    console.log(row + '/' + cell);
})
​
```

fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/acrashik/2HUtH/4/

later you cant select correct cell using that index like that:

```
 $('tr:eq('+row+') td:eq('+cell+')')
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer...I tried it in a sample code on the browser..it worked perfectly..But when I implement it on my code above and test it in my phone after building by phonegap, it doesn't work...can you help me please?? Am I doing something wrong?? I placed the code after the while function...

Comment: i can't see in your code any click events, only table and it's content generation

Comment: if you use jquery

 $('#mainDB').on('click','td',function(){
     var row = $(this).parent().index();
     var cell = $(this).index();
     console.log(row + '/' + cell);
 })

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
getDB.innerHTML=getDB.innerHTML + "<td class='tdIndex' data-index='" + i + "><h5 align='center'>" + res.rows.item(i).name + "</h5></td>";
$('td').click(function() { console.log($(this).data('index')); });
```

Store the index using the data API and retrieve it when the user clicks.